80-90' kids movie or tv show with crows/birds? in puppets style and a kid (I think a girl - actor) in a fantastic wood ?
This has been bothering me for years now... The worst part is that I dont really remember much. I remember I LOVED this movie (or tv show?) when I was a kid in the 90', but I think it could have been from the 80'. 
All I remember is one scene where the main character (I'm pretty sure it was a girl, but it could have been a boy)... was kind of surrounded of big birds (I remember them as crows, but maybe they weren't). 
Those birds where in a puppet style, and the main character was a kid/ actor, between... I dont know, maybe 10-14 years old. 
From what I remember the girl was kind of travelling in a fantastic wood, probably trying to reach the end searching for something. The scene with the birds was scary-ish. 
I really cant remember more, but this has been bothering me for years and I've even thought that I may have dreamt it... 
Almost any time I search about it in the internet i finish ending with Labyrinth as only answer, but it isn't the one I'm looking for. 
Anyways... I hope someone can help me out :c 
Thanks :3 

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please state the language of the move. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Could it be "Magic in the Mirror" from 1996? It had a young girl as the protagonist and humanoid duck puppets.
The movie is about a young girl who goes through an antique mirror with her imaginary friends to a magical world with the help of some berries she has found in a book. In the magical world they are hunted by an evil queen who rules over tea obsessed ducks and the ducks chase the girl in order to brew tea on her.
IMDB link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116959/
It had a sequel called "Magic in the Mirror: Fowl Play".
